# Why does my css-grid not scale when increasing the size of the window, the grid extends ff the screen

Tags: html, css, css-grid

College assignment,

Create a 2 page website using css grid, use media queries to make the webpages responsive to different screen widths

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFA0I.png)

This is he code for the tablet view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD221.png)

Ive tried a few things like "position: fixed" "position: relative", ive tried changing the size of the columns but nothing is helping.

The header is outside the grid as a hero image is visible in desktop view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: don't put images, put code!

Comment: Sorry it's my first time posting, I fixed it anyway